# adding options to a element using docment.createElement?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to write a function which will write a few elements, example: a `<a>`, but i want to add a `data-transition:slide` value to it. How should i do this?

Comment: And so? What did you try?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add elements with attributes with:

```
jQuery('<div/>', {
    id: 'foo',
    href: 'http://google.com',
    title: 'Become a Googler',
    rel: 'external',
    text: 'Go to Google!'
}).appendTo('#mySelector');
```

See the [Docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery2) for further information!

Answer (score 0):

May like this?

```
function f(type) {
  var ele = document.createElement(type);
  ele.setAttribute('data-transition', 'slide');
  // blabla...
  return ele; 
}
console.log(f('a'));
```